# Error 445 on MacOS with Shape.Fill.UserPicture()

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to use some code in MacOS Excel that works fine in Windows. The code adds an image to a Note since that front-end capability is missing in Excel 365 for MacOS.

Steps:

- I use GetOpenFilename() and browse for a valid file.
- I am successfully getting the image file as an Object using LoadPicture(), so I know the file and path are good.
- When I try using Fill.UserPicture(), that's when Error 445 occurs. I've also tried feeding Obj directly to UserPicture() but I get the same results.

Is this telling me that the back-end functionality is also missing?

Is there anything I can do here to get this functionality (adding an image background to a Note) in Excel for MacOS?

```
    Filestr = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Const PicX As Integer = 200
    Dim Scalar As Double
    If Filestr <> "" Then
        
        Set Obj = LoadPicture(Filestr)
        Scalar = Obj.Width / PicX
        Dim Rng As Range, Shp As Shape
        Set Rng = Selection 'Use the currently selected cell
        If Not Rng.Comment Is Nothing Then Rng.Comment.Delete
        Rng.AddComment: Rng.Comment.Text Text:=""
        
        Set Shp = Rng.Comment.Shape
        With Shp
            .Fill.UserPicture Filestr '<<<< ERROR 445 OCCURS HERE >>>>
            .Width = Obj.Width / Scalar
            .Height = Obj.Height / Scalar
        End With
        
    End If
```

Comment: If I am not wrong (And I could be wrong) but `.Shape.Fill.UserPicture <filename>` is not supported in Excel 2016/19 for Mac.

Comment: Thanks, Siddharth. Yes, it seems that all the research I've done since this post confirms that most/many properties in the Shape are read-only in Excel 2016/19 for Mac.